# How to upload images to server or local folder using ASP.NET Core 5 Web API in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

How to upload images to a server using ASP.NET Core 5 Web API?

Sample code in screenshots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFmPI.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question appropriately. it's fairly low quality the way it is and doesn't align with the minimum standard we expect

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Add your code snippet instead of screenshot, so that your problem can be reproducible it evntually help you get resolve quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var filepath = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")).Root + $@"\{newFileName}";` to combine the path, it works for me.

[For more details, you can refer this blog.](https://tutexchange.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-core-mvc-storing-in-folder/)

*You method should like below.*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile files)
{
    var path = _webHosting.WebRootPath + @"\images\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            //Getting FileName
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);

            //Assigning Unique Filename (Guid)
            var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

            //Getting file Extension
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            // concatenating  FileName + FileExtension
            var newFileName = String.Concat(myUniqueFileName, fileExtension);

            // Combines two strings into a path.
            var filepath = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")).Root + $@"\{newFileName}";

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filepath))
            {
                files.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }
            return  Ok("success");
        }
    }
    return Ok("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload a file to the file system in a `www/root` folder, and return the file path. This simple illustration demonstrates how this can be achieved by uploading the file to the file server and return the file's URL.
To achieve this, you'd have to work with an [IFormfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0).
The following are the steps to achieve that.

1. Add a static files middleware `app.UseFileServer();` in the **Startup.cs** file to handle requests for static files and serve them directly.
   e.g.

```
...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseFileServer(); // Add this middleware
app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

2. Create a folder called **wwwroot** in your root of your project and create a folder called **Files**
3. Define your file upload service interface;

```
 public interface IFileService
 {
    Task<string> UploadAsync(string path, IFormFile formFile);
 }
```

3. Create a concrete implementation of the interface as shown below;

```
public class FileService : IFileService
{
   
 public async Task<string> UploadAsync(string path, IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    // Check if the file exists else, throw an exception        
    if (file.Length < 1) throw new Exception($"No file found!");
    
    // State the file extensions you require to be uploaded.
    var allowedFileTypes = new[] { "png", "jpg"};
    
    // Get the file extension.
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);
    
    // validate the file extension type.
    if (!allowedFileTypes.Contains(fileExtension))
    {
      throw new Exception($"File format {Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)} is invalid for this operation.");
    }
     
     var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)}";

     // Create an instance of the memory stream.
     await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

     // Write file to Stream
     await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, cancellationToken);

     // Read from the start of the memoryStream
      memoryStream.Position = 0;

     // Write file to System path
      var filePath = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "Documents", fileName);
      using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

     // Write Memory Stream to FileStream
      await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, cancellationToken);

      return $"{path}/api/Files/{fileName}";
    }
 }
```

4. Create a Files controller, and inject the IFileService interface into the controller as shown below;

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class FilesController : ControllerBase
 {
   private readonly IFileService _fileService;
   
   public FilesController(IFileService fileService)
   {
            _fileService = fileService;
         
   }
   
   [HttpPost("FileUpload")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file)
   {

     var baseUrl = $"https://{Request.Host.Value}{Request.PathBase.Value}";
            
     var response = await _fileService.UploadAsync(baseUrl,file);

     return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

As simple as that.